# htaccess - keep uri but open index.php on any path

Tags: .htaccess, uri

I'm trying to find a way to do the following:

**example.com**

**When requesting:**

- https://example.com/folder1/folder2
- https://example.com/folder8374/folder8749
- ....

**Do this:**

- Prevent 404 not found error
- Open index.php, but keep uri the same and exclude index.php (https://example.com/../...)

Is there any way to solve this?

Thanks and kind regards

Comment: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dir.html#fallbackresource

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the concept of a general router for your application logic. This certainly is possible by a simple single internal rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^ /index.php [QSA,END]
```

A variant would be that:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php$
RewriteRule ^ /index.php [QSA,L]
```

That's all. You can implement such a rule in the http server's host configuration. Or, if you really have no access to that you can also use a distributed configuration file (".htaccess"), you need to enable the interpretation of such files though. Typically such file is placed in the top level of your application logic.